# Incorrect record updating

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update a specific row in a table; however, when the query runs, it updates the last record added instead of the record selected.

The SQL statement was taken straight from phpmyAdmin. I have tried "UPDATE registration_tbl SET Paid = 'PAID' WHERE ID='$row21'" and that still did not work.

Have I put something wrong in the code?

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table table-responsive-sm table-responsive-md table-responsive-lg">
                <tr>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Sex</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>Address Type</th>
                    <th>Address 1</th>
                    <th>Address 2</th>
                    <th>Home</th>
                    <th>Work</th>
                    <th>Cell</th>
                    <th>Email Address</th>
                    <th>Congregation</th>
                    <th>RMC</th>
                    <th>Auxillary</th>
                    <th>Occupation</th>
                    <th>Category</th>
                    <th>Username</th>
                    <th>Submission Date</th>
                    <th>Payment Status</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
                <?php
                    $conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

                    $result_set = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM registration_tbl");   
                    $num_messages = mysqli_num_rows($result_set);

                    $num = 0;

                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_set))
                    {
                        $row1 = $row["Title"];
                        $row2 = $row["FirstName"];
                        $row3 = $row["LastName"];
                        $row4 = $row["Sex"];
                        $row5 = $row["Age"];
                        $row6 = $row["AddressType"];
                        $row7 = $row["Address1"];
                        $row8 = $row["Address2"];
                        $row9 = $row["Home"];
                        $row10 = $row["Work"];
                        $row11 = $row["Cell"];
                        $row12 = $row["EmailAdd"];
                        $row13 = $row["Congregation"];
                        $row14 = $row["RMC"];
                        $row15 = $row["Auxillary"];
                        $row16 = $row["Occupation"];
                        $row17 = $row["Category"];
                        $row18 = $row["Username"];
                        $row19 = $row["DateSubmitted"];
                        $row20 = $row["Paid"];
                        $row21 = $row["ID"];

                        
                        $num++;

                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>$row1</td>";
                        echo "<td>$row2</td>";
                        echo "<td>$row3</td>";
                        echo "<td>$row4</td>";
                        echo "<td>$row5</td>";
                        echo "<td>$row6</td>";
                        echo "<td>$row7</td>";
                        echo "<td>$row8</td>";
                        echo "<td>$row9</td>";
                        echo "<td>$row10</td>";
                        echo "<td>$row11</td>";
                        echo "<td>$row12</td>";
                        echo "<td>$row13</td>";
                        echo "<td>$row14</td>";
                        echo "<td>$row15</td>";
                        echo "<td>$row16</td>";
                        echo "<td>$row17</td>";
                        echo "<td>$row18</td>";
                        echo "<td>$row19</td>";
                        echo "<td>$row20</td>";

                        if($row20 != "PAID")
                        {
                            echo "<td><input type='submit' class='btn btn-success' name='paid' value='PAID' /></td></tr>";
                        }
                        
                    }
                    echo "</table></br>";
                    echo "<table><tr><td>";
                    echo $num_messages . " Registration(s) Found!";
                    echo "</td></tr></table>";

                    if(isset($_POST['paid']))
                    {
                        $conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

                        $updatePaymentStmt = "UPDATE `registration_tbl` SET `Paid` = 'PAID' WHERE `registration_tbl`.`ID` = $row21;";

                        if(mysqli_query($conn, $updatePaymentStmt))
                        {
                            echo "<script>alert('Payment updated successfully!')</script>";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            echo "<script>alert('Error in updating Payment!')</script>";
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Your variables make absolutely no sense. Why do you have so many variables called $row1-21?

Comment: `WHERE ID='$row21'` makes no sense. You need to send the ID of the row you want to update, together with your form, so that you can take that value from $_POST then.

Comment: Plus it seems all your buttons have the same name, while being inside the same form. This will ultimately submit only the last value, as it will overwrite all the previous ones.

Comment: And all those numerated variables... they just make your code less understandable. Why didn't you simply use `$row["Title"]`, `$row["FirstName"]` etc. directly?

Comment: CBroe that's what I am hoping to do. The loop was to move through all the IDs as they are in the record, so referencing $row21 would correspond with the specific record.

How do you propose I do what You are suggesting?

Comment: `The loop was to move through all the IDs`...nothing wrong with the loop, but please understand that a) $row21 gets overwritten each time the loop runs, b) you're subsequently trying to use it outside that loop after it ends (so now...think logically about how that affects its value at that moment) and c) in any case it is a value coming _from_ your database. It does not indicate anything that the user selected and should be sent _to_ your database. See my answer below for how this is often done in HTML forms, in this kind of scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're going to want a separate form for each row in the table. And you'll need a hidden field in that form containing the ID so the server knows which ID to process when it receives the submission.

Remove any `<form>...</form>` tags you may have placed to wrap around the whole table, and instead use:

```
if($row20 != "PAID")
{
  echo "<td><form action='' method='post'><input type='submit' class='btn btn-success' name='paid' value='PAID' /><input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$row["ID"]."'/></form></td></tr>";
}
```

and then

```
if(isset($_POST['paid']))
{
  $id = $_POST["id"];
  ///etc, you can now use $id in a parameter in your query, to select the correct row
```

---

P.S. The rest of the code could also be greatly simplified, as others have mentioned in the comments, and you should definitely fix the SQL injection issue - that's a serious security problem.

Answer (score 1):

This *bug* comes about from a flaw in your thinking rather than unexpected behaviour in the code.

Effectively you have a `while` loop that iterates over the entire results set (from the first query) and updates the `$row*` variables. What this means is that `$row21` is always going to be the *last selected* record. If you were to chuck an `ORDER BY id DESC` on the end you'd find that the first record was always updated...

So what you actually want to do is add the `id` into the button - and make each button it's own form - so that when the form is posted the intended `id` is in the button's value.

Something like:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

$registrations = $mysqli->query($conn,"SELECT * FROM registration_tbl");   
$num_messages  = $registration->num_rows;

while ($row = $registrations->fetch_assoc() {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>{$row["Title"]}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$row["FirstName"]}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$row["LastName"]}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$row["Sex"]}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$row["Age"]}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$row["AddressType"]}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$row["Address1"]}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$row["Address2"]}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$row["Home"]}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$row["Work"]}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$row["Cell"]}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$row["EmailAdd"]}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$row["Congregation"]}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$row["RMC"]}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$row["Auxillary"]}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$row["Occupation"]}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$row["Category"]}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$row["Username"]}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$row["DateSubmitted"]}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$row["Paid"]}</td>";

    echo $row["Paid"]] !== "PAID" ?
        "<td><form method='post'><button class='btn btn-success' name='paid' value='{$row["ID"]}'>Paid</button></form></td>" :
        "<td></td>";
    }

    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table></br>";
echo "<table><tr><td>";
echo $num_messages . " Registration(s) Found!";
echo "</td></tr></table>";

if ($_POST['paid'] ?? null) {
    $sql   = "UPDATE `registration_tbl` SET `Paid` = 'PAID' WHERE `registration_tbl`.`ID` = ?";
    $query = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
    $query->bind_param("i", $_POST["paid"]);
    
    echo $query->execute() ?
        "<script>alert('Payment updated successfully!')</script>" :
        "<script>alert('Error in updating Payment!')</script>";
    }
}
```